# sdashboard: How to disable "Close" button when you create a widget

Tags: javascript

I am new developer to sDashboard and I am trying to play with it for one my Javascript projects. I realized that there is no option to disable the "Close" button on a widget. Any of you know how to disable the "Close" button when you create a new widget or change it to an existing widget?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to remove it? or have it show but does nothing?

Answer (score 0):

I just used jQuery to remove the disable buttons after loading all the widgets. This line of code should do it for you:

```
$(".sDashboard-circle-remove-icon").remove();
```